# PHP function returns same values

Tags: php

I have defined a PHP function that works absolutely fine but I am facing a problem. I am trying to call `GenerateIDNumber` function multiple times on same page with different values but its returning the same value of first time defined variables, is there any way to `close/end` the function and recall it with new values.

Here is my code

```
<?php
/* GenerateID Number */
function GenerateIDNumber($tablenames, $columnnames)
{
    global $conn;
    global $highest_id;

    $sql    = "SELECT MAX(" . $columnnames . ") as max FROM " . $tablenames;
    $rs     = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);
    if ($result[0] >= 1) {
        $highest_id = $result[0] + 1;
    } else {
        $highest_id = 1;
    }
}
/* GenerateID Number */

$highest_id    = null;
$mytable_name  = "tblleasesalespayment";
$mycolumn_name = "PaymentID";
GenerateIDNumber($mytable_name, $mycolumn_name);
$printNumber     = $highest_id;
$SaleIDGenerator = "CRV-";
$SetNumberCust   = $SaleIDGenerator . $_SESSION['ACTBRANCHID'] . date('y') . sprintf("%08s", $printNumber);

$Code1 = $SetNumberCust;

$highest_id    = null;
$mytable_name  = "tblrepossess_vehicles";
$mycolumn_name = "rp_id";
new GenerateIDNumber($mytable_name, $mycolumn_name);
$printNumber   = $highest_id;
$SetNumberCust = "REP-" . $_SESSION['ACTBRANCHID'] . date('y') . sprintf("%08s", $printNumber);
$Code2         = $SetNumberCust;
?>
```

Comment: Shudder... someone still using the `global` "feature"...

Comment: Actually your function does not return _any_ value. It has no `return` statement.

Comment: @arkascha `$highest_id` is used to combine with the returning value

Comment: instead of using global, return value from the function and assign it to highest_id

Comment: Sure, I see you try that. But that is _not_ the same as returning the value. In short words: stop using the `global` keyword! It is evil! It causes _huge_ issues. Return the value you compute from the function, then things work. Read the php documentation about how functions are used in php.

Comment: Ok I understand but instead of `global` what should I use to define a variable inside function and get value of that variable if it solves the issue any help in case

Comment: just echo the arguments you're passing to the function inside it and see, what you're getting. If values reflect the arguments, then, you need to check the sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this servers your request

```
/* GenerateID Number */
function GenerateIDNumber($tablenames, $columnnames)
{
    global $conn;

    $sql    = "SELECT MAX(" . $columnnames . ") as max FROM " . $tablenames;
    $rs     = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);
    if ($result[0] >= 1) {
        $highest_id = $result[0] + 1;
    } else {
        $highest_id = 1;
    }
    return $highest_id ;
}



 $highest_id    = null;
$mytable_name  = "tblleasesalespayment";
$mycolumn_name = "PaymentID";
$highest_id = GenerateIDNumber($mytable_name, $mycolumn_name);
$printNumber     = $highest_id;
$SaleIDGenerator = "CRV-";
$SetNumberCust   = $SaleIDGenerator . $_SESSION['ACTBRANCHID'] . date('y') . sprintf("%08s", $printNumber);

echo $Code1 = $SetNumberCust. " As Code1 value <br />";

$highest_id    = null;
$mytable_name  = "tblrepossess_vehicles";
$mycolumn_name = "rp_id";
$highest_id = GenerateIDNumber($mytable_name, $mycolumn_name);
$printNumber   = $highest_id;
$SetNumberCust = "REP-" . $_SESSION['ACTBRANCHID'] . date('y') . sprintf("%08s", $printNumber);
echo $Code2 = $SetNumberCust. " As Code2 value <br />";
```

Comment: I am still getting the same value again

Comment: Are you getting the value as 1?

Comment: No actually on first call  `GenerateIDNumber` function it returns the perfect values but on second call `GenerateIDNumber` it must check for new table and column name but it returns the value of first call

Comment: Try to echo $sql for each call and see if they are different.

Comment: this is what I am getting, `CRV-41700000000 As Code1 value, 
REP-41700000000 As Code2 value`

Comment: $sql statement looks fine

Comment: are you talking about the value 41700000000, which is same for both. If so, this values is not coming from function, it is in session $_SESSION['ACTBRANCHID']

Comment: 41700000000 is not the actual value it `$highest_id` returns the number and make codes like 41700000001, 41700000002 etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146112/discussion-between-ravinder-reddy-and-rtra).